# Use IntegerChoices in model Meta class

Tags: django, django-models

I'm creating some constraints in my `Meta` class that reference an `IntegerChoices` enum. The issue I'm having is that I can't seem to figure out *how* to reference that `IntegerChoices` enum.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    States = models.IntegerChoices('States', 'PROGRESSING INSTALLED DELETED')

    state = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=States.choices, help_text='Defines the cluster\'s current state')

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(check=models.Q(state__in=States), name='cluster_state_valid'),
        ]
```

`self.States` isn't working, no `self` object. `MyModel.States` isn't working either since `MyModel` isn't fully instantiated at this point.

Any advice/recommendation would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise that you define the enum outside the `MyModel`, such that it is interpreted first, so:

```
States = models.IntegerChoices('States', 'PROGRESSING INSTALLED DELETED')

class MyModel(models.Model):
    States = States
    state = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=States.choices, help_text='Defines the cluster\'s current state')

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(check=models.Q(state__in=States.values), name='cluster_state_valid'),
        ]
```

Comment: And then when referring to it *externally*, I would `import models.States` and use it that way?? That was why I *originally* had it coupled with the model, just to keep the contexts together.

Comment: @WillGordon: you can add it to the context of `MyModel` as well, by adding as line `States = States` (see edit). That way you can access it as `from app_name.models import States`, but also `MyModel.States`.